# Query two tables in minimum time

Tags: sql, ms-access, union

I have two tables with same kind of data. what is the fastest SQL query that looks in both tables and obtains the data from the two.  no duplicates. access 2003 or above.sample code..

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3 
FROM Table1
UNION 
SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3 
FROM Table2
```

UNION removes duplicate records (where all columns in the results are the same).

Comment: how about union ALL?. How about using UNION for more than two tables?.

Comment: UNION ALL will return all records and not remove the duplicates.  You can UNION as many tables together as you need to.  just remember, each SELECT statement within the UNION must have the same number of columns. Also, the matching columns in each query must also have similar data types.

Comment: **@user3509364**, any feedback?  Did my answer solve your question?  Or, are you still needing further help/clarification?